# A way to determine sequence pattern?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there a way to determine a pattern in a sequence which elements are known to be the result of a modulus operation ?

Say I have 0,1,2,0,1,2,0. 
It is $\{i mod 3\}$ for $i$ going from $0$ to $6$

That is what I mean by modulus (modulo?) operation,

Or is it by trial and error most likely ?

Cheers.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific than "result of a modulus operation". *Everything* is a result of a modulus operation.

Comment: If this is a theoretical question im not really sure what your asking, but if you just need help evaluating a specific sequence, try to search for it on OEIS, you might get a match.

Comment: It is a theorical question, for my homework I need to determine the pattern (using modulo) of a sequence, I am wondering if there is any specific manner to come up with a solution or if I better start writing a java program to apply modulo on all 8 bit integers and analyse the data ?

Comment: As the answer from @did suggests, you've still not been specific enough about the kind of modular operation permitted. If it has to be of the form $i\bmod m$ for some unknown $m$, then you just look at how long it takes to repeat. But if it can be $f(i)\bmod m$ for some complicated function $f$, then you're really back to square one. So: what kind of modular operations are allowed?

Comment: For example, see: http://oeis.org/A204425 Such sequences could arise from many things and without knowing more numbers it could be anything.

Answer (score 1):

> Say I have 0,1,2,0,1,2,0.

This is i(i+1)(i+4)(6i<sup>3</sup>+6i<sup>2</sup>+3i+4) mod 7 for i going from i = 0 to i = 6 hence the next term of the sequence is 0 (in case you would have the idea that the next term should be, say... 1).